# ValidateInput(false) and AllowHtml attributes still cause 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have on my model:

```
public class EmailTemplateModel
{
    public int EmailTemplateId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [Required]        
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And on my controller:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddNewTemplate(EmailTemplateEditorModel model)
{
}
```

Yet I am getting the following error:

**A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client**

Why am I getting these errors even though this check should be disabled using the ValidateInput/AllowHtml attributes?  Looking at other posts its not clear if I need both or just one of these attributes...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

to your `web.config`. See [ASP.Net 4.0 Breaking Changes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes). Despite confusing configuration value, this is a breaking change between **3.5** and **4.0** - validation now runs earlier in the pipeline, before MVC gets a chance to disable it based on your attributes.

Comment: This works!!! Thanks!!! Are we pointing requestValidationMode to target different framework or assembly version? I am still not able to understand...